# Threshold voltage for high and low in a BeagleBone

Tags: beagleboneblack, threshold

It is said that 0V indicates a LOW and 3.3V indicates a HIGH. I was wondering if there is a threshold voltage for the HIGH and LOW logic level. Tried searching it, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specs you want are VIH and VIL.  Download the datasheet from TI for more info.

VIH is 2.0v and VIL is 0.8v.  The hysteresis minimum is 0.265v.